# The given key was not present in the dictionary. with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am trying to link a project in **C#** with **MySQL** (***localhost***)
but i getting error while executing login

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException was unhandled
HResult=-2146232969
Message=The given key was not present in the dictionary.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetCharacterSet(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetFieldMetaData41()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetFieldMetaData()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnMetadata(Int32 count)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadMetaData()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextResult()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at College_Student.login.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\zMJ\Desktop\College_Student\College_Student\login.cs:line 87
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
```

this what i try  connection

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(" Server=localhost;Database=college_management;Uid=root;Pwd=12345678;CharSet=utf8;");
```

and using library

```
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
```

and in button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i=0;
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM  admins where name='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "' ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

    if (i == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
    else
    {
        this.Hide();
        new home().Show();

    }

    con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: What happens if I type `x' OR 1 == 1; --` into your `textBox1`? You should be using parameterized queries. `ExecuteNonQuery` is for insertions/deletings that just return the number of rows affected, you should be using `ExecuteScalar` with an SQL of `SELECT COUNT(*)...`, but certainly fix the parameterized query...

Comment: @RonBeyer get the same error  my above code from youtube https://youtu.be/P7aaaLvWy_s?t=505

Comment: What are the full exception details (as text, not an image)? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/342k

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by using a character set (for your database or column) that Connector/NET doesn't support. (E.g., see [MySQL bug 58244](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58244).) This is generally solved by updating to the latest version of the library from NuGet.

If you are already running the latest version of Connector/NET, try switching to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), which is a [more reliable](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs) MySQL ADO.NET library for C#.

Comment: the problem in **Collation** of column For example i can make request for column which its Collation **utf8_general_ci** so that the id is **integer** when i make its Collation utf8_general_ci its not change as shown in this image [link](https://pasteboard.co/IQ51D8D.png) also if i make request for count(name) or **SELECT* ** or **SELECT SUM()** will get the same error

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of MySql.Data, or switching to MySqlConnector?

Comment: yes update Mysql.data.dll but get   Warning ` The primary reference "MySql.Data" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". WindowsFormsApplication1 `

Comment: .NET 4.0 Client Profile is also extremely old (and no longer supported by Microsoft since 12 Jan 2016: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework). Is there a reason you haven't updated to .NET 4.8? Continuing to use obsolete and unsupported software will result in these kind of compatibility errors.

Comment: Is these problems can be fixed with visual studio 2015 ?

Comment: Hopefully VS2015 can at least target .NET 4.5.2 if the correct Targeting Pack is installed. But again, it's also an obsolete software version. There is a free Community Edition of VS2019 available; can you update to that (or have your employer pay for an upgrade to Professional)?

Comment: Thank you , Also Get error      **An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=2016.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1cee9f8bde3db106' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: Are you using 8.0.19? That error was supposedly fixed in 8.0.18: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96614. If you're still having problems with 8.0.19, then I would recommend switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ which has no third-party dependencies.

Comment: thank you very much for your time , and your support I have updating mysql.data.dll to 8.0.19 now works great with VS 2015 Many thanks