# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.' C# windows application

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on c# project, I am storing data to MySql database hosted on local server, form storing data to database but when I try to fetch data form MySql in datagridview it show error of

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was
>   not present in the dictionary.'

my connection code is

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server = 192.168.0.xxx; Port = 3306; Database = databaset; User ID = xxx; Password = xxxx; CharSet = utf8;");
    MySqlCommand command;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable table;
```

when i change server ip to localhost it starts working. so i think there is an issue with the connection string but unable to figure it out.
Code to show data in datagridview is

```
string Query = "SELECT id AS 'ID',driver_name AS 'Driver Name',driver_license_no AS 'License No',driver_cnic_no AS 'Driver CNIC No' FROM table_name ORDER BY ID Desc";
            command = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: Can you see under debugger which line throws an error?

Comment: adapter.Fill(table); this line throws an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59739008/23633

Comment: @BradleyGrainger i checked that question and tried but no success, i am wondering by using local connection (like localhost instead of IP) its working fine but when i connection with server (like giving IP instead of localhost) it shows error, by same connection i successfully inserted data into server database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. Please check if you are using the latest **MySQL.Data** library.

Comment: Dear @hasnu zama yes i am using updated MySQL.Data library

Comment: I tried your code (till adapter.Fill method) and its working fine. Can you please post code snippet on which we can reproduce this issue

Comment: yes when i connect application with localhost it works fine but when i connect it with server it shows error

Comment: Mysql.data dll version was my issue, which was incompatible with the DBcolumn type. So I had to upgrade as well as keep the version in sync with my .net framework version.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue by using **MySql.Data.Dll version 6.3.6.0** reference and it's working fine now.

Comment: Mysql.data dll version was my issue, which was incompatible with the DBcolumn type. So I had to upgrade as well as keep the version in sync with my .net framework version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like connection string has extra space signs:

```
Server=192.168.0.xxx;Port=3306;Database=databaset;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx;CharSet=utf8;
```

Comment: i tried by removing the spaces from connection string but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a collation issue on the other server, try without the charset and see:

```
Server=192.168.0.xxx;Port=3306;Database=databaset;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx;
```

Comment: i tried it by removing CharSet=utf8; but no success

Answer (score 0):

On the server database check if "Collation" value of each column is the same as column datatype. the difference between them might raise such error.

This error might be solved by selecting “Table default” value in “Collation” option for the all columns in a table.

there is a solution on this page which might help:
[To Overcome "The Given Key Was Not Present In The Dictionary" Exception In MySQL](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/to-overcome-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-exception-in-mysql/)